# ModuleNotFoundError while coding a Python Discord bot

Tags: python, discord, replit

I am trying to get my Discord bot to execute commands because it stopped after an update in the way bots work in discord I believe. I am stuck at an error that says ModuleNotFound when I try to import discord interaction package. I have tried installing it through the windows cmd AND through the Replit command prompt. It says it's installed successfully but when I run my file the error pops up. What should I do?

```
import imaplibnteractions
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import music

cogs = [music]

bot = interactions.Client(token="My token")

for i in range(len(cogs)):
    cogs[i].setup(bot)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Fritten Bot is on!')

bot.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your repl, click on show hidden files, open replit.nix file, in that add your
package. for example, pkgs.discord  and that should work...

Comment: i don't have such a file :(